# unable to connect to redis using gcp external ip

Tags: redis

I followed the following instructions and installed a redis-server on gcp.

https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/setting-up-redis

I set the firewall so that port `6379` is open to all ip (`0.0.0.0/0`)

I then create another GCP instance in the same project. When I tried to connect to the redis-server I just setup(say on a machine with 1.2.3.4 externam ip), I was not able to do so. But when I use that machine's internal IP, it worked.

Also, when I tried to connect to the redis-server on my local machine, it failed(timeout).

When I nmap the machine with port 6379 from another instance in the same gcp project with the machine's **external** ip it shows

```
PORT     STATE    SERVICE
6379/tcp filtered unknown
```

When I nmap the machine with port 6379 from another instance in the same gcp project with the machine's **internal** ip it shows

```
PORT     STATE SERVICE
6379/tcp open  unknown
```

When I nmap the machine with port 6379 from my local machine in the same gcp project with the machine's **external** ip it shows

```
PORT     STATE    SERVICE
6379/tcp filtered redis
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out what went wrong.

I was not setting the correct `target`.

I thought I could just type anything in the target field, but it turns out what goes in that field will be the machines the rule applies to.

After I selected `All instances in the network` for `targets` everything went well. Though when I nmap from internal network, port `6379` is still an unknwon service, but it's open and I can use redis-cli to connect to the redis server